# Odoo How to allow access button for many group of user?

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-10

I am trying to allow access for two group of user as this following code :

```
<record model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">sale.order.approve</field>
        <field name="model">sale.order</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_order_form"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath expr="/form/header/button[@name='action_approve']" position="replace">
                <!-- <field name="groups_id" eval="[(4,ref('group_lead')),(4,ref('group_sm'))]"/> -->
                <button name="action_approve" states="pending" string="Approve" class="btn-primary o_sale_confirm" type="object"  groups="[ref('group_lead'),ref('group_sm')]" />
            </xpath>
        </field>
    </record>
```

However this doesn't work?

Do you have any solution to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax to given groups are wrong.

```
<record model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">sale.order.approve</field>
    <field name="model">sale.order</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_order_form"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="/form/header/button[@name='action_approve']" position="replace">
            <!-- <field name="groups_id" eval="[(4,ref('group_lead')),(4,ref('group_sm'))]"/> -->
            <button name="action_approve" states="pending" string="Approve" class="btn-primary o_sale_confirm" type="object"  groups="account.group_account_user,account.group_account_manager,account.group_account_invoice" />
        </xpath>
    </field>
</record>
```

Here I gave a sample group, you can add yours.

Comment: I edit my code to this 

<button name="action_approve" states="pending" string="Approve" class="btn-primary o_sale_confirm" type="object"  groups="permission_order.group_lead,permission_order.group_sm" />

However it doesn't work yet.

Comment: this is an working example, <button name="action_cancel" states="manual,progress" string="Cancel Folio" type="object" groups="base.group_user"/> just try to check your groups

Comment: I understand that, but I want to make it works for many groups of user.

Comment: and also check the states you have defined

Comment: This answer is correct did you updgrade your module? did you put this xml file to the manifest? to make sure that you updated the code change the string attribute to see if your code is running!!